# False positives with AWS DMS validations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, dms

I am using DMS to move data (5.200.000 records) between an RDS SQL Server Express database and an RDS MySQL database. The number of records transferred is perfect : every record count per table matches exactly.

However when running the data validation step with the AWS tool, I get a lot of mismatched records that I believe is an issue in the DMS validation process at the driver level (charset configuration probably or character encoding).

Example:

```
RECORD_DIFF [{'Title': 'سلام ژوند څنګه دی (1) '}, {'Title': 'سلام ژوند څنګه دی (1) ??'},]
```

If I do the select query directly in the MySQL database with MySQL Workbench I get exactly the same emojis as I the DMS validation tool gets from the SQL Server.

Besides this I am also getting a lot of RECORD_DIFF [{'Content': '<VALUE_PRINT_NOT_SUPPORTED>'}, {'Content': '<VALUE_PRINT_NOT_SUPPORTED>'},] which I am not sure what they mean querying both database I see the values perfectly for those rows.

Should I consider using another validation tool or there is a known way to address the problems above?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: We end up using AWS DMS only for data migration but for data validation we didn't as it was giving a low of mismatched recordss that were "false positives" probably because of the ODBC underlying driver.

This was the tool that we used at the end - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=103016 although it was again with some bugs.

My recommendation would be to get an Expert Support for AWS if your plan includes it or you are willing to pay for such.